# Where should I create my aggregate root? in api or frontend?

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, rest, aggregate

I am writing a simple application to apply what I have learned so far in DDD.

I have the following mysql tables in my api server

**Sales**

| Column |  |
| --- | --- |
| id | pk, int |
| title | varchar |
| description | varchar |

**Images**

| Column |  |
| --- | --- |
| id | pk, int |
| url | varchar |
| sale_id | fk, int |

I have the following endpoints

```
GET  /v1/sales
GET  /v1/sales/:id
POST /v1/sales
```

On the frontend I have a `SaleView` which displays the sale with the information AS WELL AS the images.

So my question is when the `SaleView` loads, should the frontend call `GET /v1/sales/123` and then call `GET /v1/sales/123/images (I have to create this one)` or should it just call `GET /v1/sales/123` and it automatically aggregates the images into the response? or finally should I make another endpoint to do aggregation such as `GET /v1/salesAggregate/123`?

I am not quite sure. The other solution I have in mind is create entities without thinking about database. For example:

**SaleEntity**

```
var id: UUID
var title: String
var description: String
var imagesUrls: [String]
```

and keep my endpoints the same and the first design refers only to the database design so when I get an api call to `GET /v1/sales/123` all I do in the controller is query the `Sales` table as well as the `Images` table and then create a `SaleEntity` which then gets mapped to the response of the endpoint?

I am leaning more towards the last solution, but I am confused as which is the correct path to take. I know both works but I would like to learn the correct habits.

Comment: Both are fine and both have very little to do with DDD. So, why is DDD relevant to this question?

Comment: @Laiv: DDD incorporated ideas like aggregates which are surely older than the term DDD itself, or can be used without other DDD concepts. Nevertheless it is not uncommon for people today to ask about these ideas as if they were "DDD exclusive".

Comment: The problem is then that the possible answers are left to interpretation. Yours is good and I upvoted it because I find it useful. However, mine would touch on different subjects as if it was different question. That's why I ask why is DDD relevant. If it's not, then the question is about API modelling regardless DDD. If it's, then yours hits the nail because it covers the two subjects.

Comment: @Laiv my thinking was to model the problem in DDD but I understand where I went wrong. Thank you for the comment and clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you truly want to treat sale entities (with images included) as an [aggregate](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html) in your domain model, you should not allow to GET or PUT sales and images individually, and use your `SaleEntity` model as a blueprint. Citing Fowler:

> Aggregates are the basic element of transfer of data storage - you request to load or save whole aggregates. Transactions should not cross aggregate boundaries.

Let me add that the ideas of a "correct path" or "correct habits" look off-track to me. The approach of treating sales and images individually (and so as entities / aggregates on their own) is neither more nor less correct - it is just a *different* design decision.

Of course, one of the two decisions may be better suited for creating your specific application. This depends ultimately on what your system will finally *do* with those entities. If sale entities together with the images can always be treated as a unit (for example, in any load and save operations, or maybe by certain business logic operations), go ahead with your "`SaleEntity` with images" model. If, however, you may want to allow image entities with an empty `sale_id`, with operations on them outside of a "sale" context, then you better implement those two entities separately and provide separate endpoints.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this makes sense. I did more reading + your answer clarified some things. I understand my problem is that I was thinking from the persistent layer rather than thinking about my "domain" which mislead me and probably made me ask the wrong question.I also understand the above is not that big of a deal to think in DDD but I am learning and I wanted to apply what I learned even if it is on a small scale. I am reading the blue book. Thank you